# Obtaining elements as jQuery-objects fails when bracketing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm retrieving elements from a TABLE using the following syntax.

```
$("#table").children().children().children().html();
```

That gives me the contents of the **first** TD. Then I moved to the second one and discovered that picking it using the bracket-syntax below gives me an error message saying that *html()* is not a method of that object.

```
$("#table").children().children().children()[1].html();
```

Instead, I have to use *innerHTML* peoperty instead, like so.

```
$("#table").children().children().children()[1].innerHTML;
```

My impression is that I'm doing something wrong. While getting the result I want, I can't help feeling that there are more recommended ways to resolve this kind of call. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you want iterate over all `td`s you can also use `$('td').each(function() {...});`. If you only care about the first and second `td` and already have a reference to the first `td`, you can use `.next()` to get the `td` that immediately follows it.

Comment: @itsjeyd Actually, I'm doing something else. I'm not iterating but I'm not going for the **second** neither. I'm targeting four different elements with indexes like 143, 237 etc.

Comment: I see. In that case there's nothing to add to the answers you already got ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `html` is a jQuery function, but the `[1]` gives you the DOM element.

You can use `.eq(n)` to get the nth element:

```
$("#table").children().children().children().eq(1).html();
```

...but if you're looping through them, it's very inefficient to repeat the above. Instead, consider `each`:

```
$("#table").children().children().children().each(function() {
    // Use $(this).html(); for each cell's contents
});
```

**Update** In a comment you said:

> I'm targeting four different elements with indexes like 143, 237 etc.

In that case, remember the initial set of elements, then use `.eq` as necessary:

```
var cells = $("#table").children().children().children();
cells.eq(143).html(...);
cells.eq(237).html(...);
```

---

You might also consider something that's less fragile if you adjust your table structure (for instance, perhaps you add a `colgroup` or `rowgroup` and now there are different levels):

```
var cells = $("#table td");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you use index to access the element it returns a dom element reference not a jQuery object so the `.html()` method won't be there.

```
var first  = $("#table").find('td').eq(0).html();
var second =  $("#table").find('td').eq(1).html();
```

---

or

```
var $tds = $('#table td')
var first  = $tds.eq(0).html();
var second = $tds.eq(1).html();
```